# SOAPUI: Cannot find the icon to open application on mac

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I am having trouble opening soap ui.

I have gone onto their website and downloaded SoapUI-5.0.0-mac-bin.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/5.0.0/

I have then unzipped it and have many different files but there is none with the icon to open the application. Someone said to open soapui-5.0.0.jar in the bin folder but when I do I get an error saying it cannot be launched and to check the console for possible error messages.

I cant seem to find the error message on the console - I have very limited technical ability I think haha I am running 10.9.2 apple OS if that helps at all.

I would attach screenshots but my reputation isn't good enough

Answer (score 0):

In the bin folder there is a file named soapui.sh. To start SoapUI you can run this file from the terminal.

A possible easier way to run SoapUI is to download the SoapUI-5.0.0.dmg file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/5.0.0/. Running that file will start an installer for SoapUI. Once installed you will get an icon on your desktop that you can use to start SoapUI.